# Detect movement of child window in MFC when parent moves

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I'm Interested in getting an update in a CView derived window when the parent window moves.

Normally one would use the `ON_WM_MOVE()` macro and implement the `afx_msg void OnMove(int x, int y)` message handler. However, this handler is only called when the CView moves relatively to the toplevel parent and is not called when the parent moves.

For me this is an issue, because when my child window moves to an different monitor the underlying hardware changes. Therefore I need to get an update to switch to the right monitor hardware.

Is there a message I'm missing that could inform my child window of the monitor change? Should I detect the movement in the toplevel window and pump a custom message to my CView? Or is there an alternative even better method to detect monitor change?

Hopefully someone can give me a good advise.

Comment: I think your best bet is to trap it at the parent level since you already know how to do that.  I don't think there is a predefined event for switching monitors.